# PHP: How to store temporary POST data before submit?

Tags: php, http-post

I'm developing an application in mobile view using CakePHP, where there's no Javascript code can run.

My scenario:

In user login form, users clicked submit button. But before the data submitted and users go to the next page, I make an 'interruption' page (renders a new view). In there, contains "Facebook" and "No, thanks" button. When they click "Facebook", they will connect their Facebook accounts. But, if they click "No, thanks", the login continue.

My question is, how can I make that "No, thanks" button? Because if I use `<input type="submit">` button, the form that contain its data is in previous page, so this button will not be clicked. And, how to store POST data, and when that "No thanks" button clicked, then, the data submitted?

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` or hidden form fields. Alternatively, give the users the facebook option with the original form.

Comment: 1. Set the action of your form to middle page (?nothanks.php?). From there based on the response you can decide the next action.
2. Set the FB & no thanks button in a div and hide it, if the user clicks on Register of type "button" show the div. u can do this using css iteself, ( :after)

Answer (score 2):

You can either store the data in session, or you can make the "no thanks" button the submit button of a form where all the data from the previous page is stored in hidden form fields.

Personally for a number of reasons, I would prefer to utilize sessions, but since you are even asking this question, I am guessing you are unfamiliar with usage of session data.

Comment: A major reason why you need to use sessions here would be, we are dealing with passwords. User sends you a secret password in one page - don't send it back in plaintext.

Comment: Either storing data using session or hidden fields, it still has problem. Because the password has been hashed by CakePHP in second form, the login validation may always return 'false' which makes users to repeat filling username and password again.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler question would be:
To make these two forms on single page but with LOTS of vertical or horizontal space in between user login form & 'interruption' page so user seeing the login form can't see interruption section although both are within same `<form></form>` tag. Then, the the submit button is simply a link to interruption section of the same form. this link is simple an `<a>` tag with inline linking, which would hide the login form & display interruption page without needing javascript.  similar to links to Go to Test Section A on this page

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/bookmarkscroll.htm

Further then in the interruption section you can use a real submit button which makes a POST back to request the server.

**[edit]**

This workaround is based on assumption that user doesn't scroll far enough. Because most users won't, making it 1step process for them instead of 2process which is specially important on mobile. And if somebody does then the empty form gets submitted to the server & then we can run validation & return a error to the user. where he/she can fill the complete form. so This is a good workaround better than storing the data in session & making two POST request for every user login over mobile network which are generally unreliable.

Comment: The user will see a scrollbar and when/if he scrolls down the other form will appear.

Comment: Without javascript, it still would work based on URL parameter string. no problems

Comment: The problem is that you are not really hiding the other form, you are simply hoping the user doesn't scroll far enough.

Comment: Yes, that's right. As most users won't, so this would be 1step process instead of 2process which is specially important on mobile. And if somebody does then the empty form gets submitted to the server & then we can run validation & return a error to the user. where he/she can fill the complete form. so This is a good workaround better than storing the data in session & making two POST request for every user login

Comment: Hmmm... well. Let's see if the OP likes it.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I am being downvoted for a plausible solution.

Comment: That was my downvote.  I saw this as an inelegant hack.  Am still not convinced it should be used.  (However I cannot change my downvote anymore.)

Comment: Fair enough. But In my experience the network requests over mobile  should be kept minimum as possible because users are moving constanly & there could be places where there is no or low signal leading to errors or timeouts, bad for mutli-step forms .

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be just to combine both forms into one form.  Then you don't have to make 2 http requests.  Maybe all you need to do is to add one extra button to the original form "Login with FaceBook" next to the other submit button.

Comment: There are still some serious people who don't have facebook accounts. And I usually dint feel good when authorizing some random app with my facebook account.

Comment: @AyeshK: You seem to be saying something like this - that if some people don't drink coffee and only water, then coffee shouldn't be an extra option, for those who like it.  I agree with your comment about passing your FaceBook details to a random app, but this is the requirement of the OP. I guess people don't have to do it if they don't want to.

Comment: Nice example Stefan. No offense I just said "some people will probably prefer per-site login and not to depend entirely on Fb thing".  :)